# WpContentNode[] is not assignable to type WpPage[] error in Gatsby+WordPress+TypeScript project

Tags: wordpress, typescript, graphql, gatsby, graphql-codegen

This error occurs within a Gatsby + WordPress + TypeScript project component when pulling WordPress page data along with its child page data via GraphQL.

**Type 'WpContentNode[]' is not assignable to type 'WpPage[]'.**

On line:

`const pages: WpPage[] = page?.wpChildren?.nodes;`

The data is being fetched from a GraphQL query in the page component:

```
query {
  allWpPage(filter: { databaseId: { eq: 383 } }) {
    nodes {
      ...standardPageFields
      wpChildren {
        nodes {
          ... on WpPage {
            id
            uri
            title
            ...etc
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This part of the query appears to *not* be meshing well with the generated TypeScript interfaces:

```
wpChildren {
  nodes {
    ... on WpPage {
      id
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

`wpChildren.nodes` is typed as `WpContentNode[]` even though it's pulling from `... on WpPage`. I'd think it would be typed as `WpPage[]` as a result of the `... on WpPage` within the query.

**These type definitions are all being generated with `graphql-codegen`.** The majority are working fine. Only running into this one issue with matching the appropriate type to a `... on WpPage` query.

How can I type `wpChildren.nodes` as `WpPage[]`? They are child pages of the parent node.

Note: We're avoiding the use of `any` to make this error go away, so that is not a viable solution for me. We're aiming to adhere to strict typing.

Thanks in advance for any insight.